# how to create a web service for using the web connector quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks

I am very new to QuickBooks and web services, I am trying to connect my web shopping cart application to quickbooks using the web connector. I created a .qwc file and imported on the web connector but I am not sure of what web service should I generate? what data should I handle in the web service? I generated class files from wsdl file what is my next step? When I try to update from web connector it always throws "QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml' The request failed with an empty response ...."

Comment: Post your code, and tell us what programming language you're in so that we can actually help you.